# MySQL Full text boolean search with tags

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, tags

I've never done searching from MYSQL before, but I need to implement a search. I have three tables: `articles`, `articles_tags`, and `tags`.

The table `articles` holds the first thing I would like to search on, the `title` field.

The table `articles_tags` is a pivot table which relates `articles` and `tags` together. `articles_tags` has two fields, that are: `articles_id` and `tag_id`.

And, the table `tags` holds the second thing I would like to search on, the `name` field.

My problem is, I need a way to search the `title` field, and each of the tags that relate to that article (`tags.name`) and return a relevancy (or sort by relevancy) for the specific article.

What would be a good way to implement this? I'm pretty sure it can't be done from just one query so two queries, and then `mixing` the relevancies together, would be ok.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Forgot to say, if I could give more weighting to matching a tag than matching a word in the title, that would be awesome. I'm not really asking for anyone to write the thing, but give me some direction. I'm a bit of a newbie in both PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the answer given by @james.c.funk but making some changes.

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, 
  MATCH (a.title) AGAINST (?) AS relevance
FROM articles AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (articles_tags AS at
  JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = at.tag_id AND t.name = ?))
  ON (a.id = at.article_id)
WHERE MATCH (a.title) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY IF(t.name IS NOT NULL, 1.0, relevance) DESC;
```

I assume you want tag matches to match against the full string, instead of using a fulltext search.

Also using one left outer join instead of two, because if a join to `articles_tags` is satisfied, then surely there is a tag.  Put the tag name comparison inside the join condition instead of in the `WHERE` clause.

The boolean mode makes `MATCH()` returns 1.0 on a match, which makes it useless as a measure of relevance.  So do an extra comparison in the select-list to calculate the relevance.  This value is between 0.0 and 1.0.  Now we can make a tag match sort higher by treating it as having relevance of 1.0.

Comment: Hi Bill. I've read in a few places that using a JOIN with FULLTEXT is bad, as it forces MySQL into running a full table scan and losing valuable performance. I'm going to run a test on this now to see if what I read was true.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid, depends on which table is accessed first.  MySQL does joins using a nested-loop algorithm, so if you use FULLTEXT to restrict the number of rows matched in the first table, then use that to look up rows in a joined table, it should be no problem.  But if you scan another table table first, then use FULLTEXT in the join condition, or even worse, use a *column* of the first table as the pattern to search for in the FULLTEXT search (I don't know offhand if this is even possible), then it would be costly.  You may have to use STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

Is it worth at this time, recommending that you look at offloading the job of search to something that is actually written just for that purpose?

In our products, we use MySQL to store data, but index all of our data with Lucene (via Solr - but that's irrelevant).

It's worth giving it a look into, because it's relatively simple to set up, it's very powerful and it's a lot easier than trying to manipulate the database into doing what you want.

Sorry this isn't a direct answer to the question, I just feel that this kind of thing is always worth mentioning in this scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I have done this in the past.  It looks slow, but I think you will find it is not.

I added a little complexity to show what else can easily be done.  In this example an article will get 1 point for a partial title match, 2 points for a partial tag match, 3 points for an exact tag match, and 4 points for an exact title match.  It then adds those up and sorts by the score.

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN a.title LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN t.name LIKE '%keyword%' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN t.name = 'keyword' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END
    +
    CASE WHEN a.title = 'keyword' THEN 4 ELSE END
  ) AS score
FROM article a, articles_tags at, tags t
WHERE a.id = at.article_id
AND at.tag_id=t.id
AND (a.title LIKE '%keyword%' OR t.name LIKE '%keyword%')
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY score;
```

NOTES: This will not return articles without tags. I used simple joins to reduce the noise in the query and highlight just what is doing the scoring. To include articles without tags just make the joins left joins.

Answer (score 0):

This quick demo query is far from optimized but should be a good starting point

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT a.id, a.title, 
  MATCH (a.title) AGAINST ('$s_search_term') AS title_score,
  SUM(MATCH (t.name) AGAINST ('$s_search_term')
) AS tag_score
FROM articles AS a
LEFT JOIN articles_tags AS at
  ON a.id = at.article_id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t
  ON t.id = at.tag_id
WHERE MATCH (a.title) AGAINST ('$s_search_term') 
  OR MATCH (t.name) AGAINST ('$s_search_term')
GROUP BY a.id) AS table1
ORDER BY 2*tag_score + title_score DESC
```

You may want to normalize tag_score by dividing it by COUNT(t.id). Sorry but it's easier to give the query than to explain how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into sphinx, http://www.sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score -1):

Funny it is the 3rd question about pretty much the same problem I see in 2 days, check out these two posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357336/1357384#1357384), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360077/1360100#1360100)

Comment: I looked at those two but fail to see how they relate to my problem.

Comment: What's more funny is that this is really a comment, not an answer.